# Rails Seed data not updating in app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5 and I had seed data before with the following code:

```
packages = Package.create!([{package_name: 'First', package_price: 199 }, {package_name: 'Second', package_price: 399}, {package_name: 'Third', package_price: 129}])
```

I changed the seed data `package_price` to the following after doing `Package.destroy_all` and running `bundle exec rake db:seed` to reseed the table:

```
packages = Package.create!([{package_name: 'First', package_price: 99 }, {package_name: 'Second', package_price: 299}, {package_name: 'Third', package_price: 129}])
```

I'm very confused because my app still maintains the original `package_price` even after I've changed it.  I've gone into the console and tested out and all of the updated seed data works there fine, but in my app it either still shows the original data.

Anyone understand why the app won't update and why there's a conflict between the console and the app display seed data?

Appreciate ay help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. What records do you see on the screen? Packages First, Second and Third or Silver, Gold and CMA?

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo Sorry - Copied and pasted wrong code.  I've corrected it now.  Please let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense. Are you sure the packages were actually destroyed when you ran Package.destroy_all? Maybe a package is still associated with other table, and you did not specify how to proceed when deleting the parent. So run Package.destroy_all again and then Product.count and tell me if you get 0.

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo Yup. I do indeed get 0.  So that's not it, but there is a `has_many` association - could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well I learned a thing or two about caches.  I had no clue that you could cache an instance variable.  Thanks to this article that gave me some direction: http://cmme.org/tdumitrescu/blog/2014/01/careful-what-you-memoize/

I ran `Rails.cache.clear` in console and that solved the problem.